# Display Bitmap in gray scale of one color space component value only

Tags: java, android, bitmap, rgb, grayscale

I would like to know how can I display color Bitmap in gray-scale. It must be done for each color space components separately. Probably it is not clear, therefore I uploaded images to visualize it: 
[Grey-scale images visualisation](http://imgur.com/T6gWZbD&x0RrRU6&ezpj8gV&YSn0ylD#0)
These Bitmaps are displayed after color conversion into one color space component: B, G, R, S (blue, green red, saturation). I want to repeat it in Android. I tried something like this:

```
case 'blue': pixels[i]=Color.argb(alpha,0,0,blue);
```

But it does not work at all. How to remove unnecessary components and present a Bitmap in gray-scale with a value of one color space component?

Comment: Did you try ColorMatrixColorFilter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to use ColorMatrixColorFilter to display the saturation because the formula can't be turned into a matrix, and it's probably easier to use the same technique for all the components rather than handling that as a special case.

Your included code will produce a blue bitmap, to display the blue component in grey scale you need to copy it to the red and green channels also:

```
case 'blue': pixels[i]=Color.argb(alpha,blue,blue,blue);
```

Likewise for red:

```
case 'red': pixels[i]=Color.argb(alpha,red,red,red);
```

and green:

```
case 'green': pixels[i]=Color.argb(alpha,green,green,green);
```

For the saturation you will need to compute it. Here is one formula:

```
case 'saturation':         
     int rgbMax = red > green ? (red > blue ? red : blue) : (green > blue ? green : blue);
     if(rgbMax == 0)
     {
         pixels[i]=Color.argb(alpha,0,0,0);
     }
     else
     {
         int rgbMin = red < green ? (red < blue ? red : blue) : (green < blue ? green : blue);
         int saturation = (255 * (rgbMax - rgbMin)) / rgbMax;
         pixels[i]=Color.argb(alpha,saturation,saturation,saturation);
     }
```

If you are not satisfied with the result then refer to the [formula for HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV).

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems that it solved the problem. Unfortunately, I said only about saturation, but I need also the same for hue, and value.

Comment: Nevertheless, I am not sure if you know, but I have access to three element array HSV -> access to hue, saturation, and value. But I need to calculate it somehow tu put similarly to saturation. Any idea? I tried to find it, but unsuccessfully...

Comment: Here is some code showing how to calculate HSV: http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/color/t_convert.html. Value is just rgbMax. Hue is a value from 0 to 360, so you will have to scale it to 0-255.